# how to load datamember after grouping in data report at Visual Basic 6.0

Tags: sql, filter, vb6

my query before grouping is working :

```
private sub cmd_report1_Click()
    if data.rs1.state = adstateopen then
        data.rs1.state.close
    end if
    data.rs1.state.open
    report1.show
    data.rs1.filter = "[date] >= '" & text1.text & "'"
end sub
```

but after i group it....i can't filter it any more

```
private sub cmd_report1_Click()
    if data.rs1_grouping.state = adstateopen then
        data.rs1_grouping.state.close
    end if
    data.rs1_grouping.state.open
    report1.show
    data.rs1_grouping.filter = "[date] >= '" & text1.text & "'"
end sub
                                  ^
                                  |
                         got error here i think
```

this is show of my data environment before and after environment

before

```
data
- connection1
  -(sql) rs1
    category
    date
    name
    ...
```

after

```
data
- connection1
 -(sql) rs1 grouped using rs1_grouping
   -(folder) summary fields in rs1_grouping
     category
   -(folder) detail_fields in rs1
     category
     date
     name
     ...
```

can you help me how to fix it??

Comment: Try applying the filter before showing the report.  If that doesn't work, then bind the report object to the data object after applying the filter.  Maybe one of those ideas will work.

Comment: it still error...there, i add my data environment...it became foldered after i group category....because of that i cant filter it anymore, but i need to filter it like query up there....can you help me?? @BobRodes